# AWS Architecture for backend to edge locations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, serverless

I currently have a react web app that is globally distributed via AWS cloudfront.

I want to know how to architect a server and DB so that they are also globally distributed. Bonus for as serverless as possible

My thoughts and knowledge right now are aligned with the following:

1) You should turn your server into a docker image and run it with a container management solution like kubernetes or AWS Fargate. This way it's serverless and you could deploy the cluster to different regions.

2) The DB is the bottleneck. If you pick a relational DB even like Aurora compatible PostgreSQL you have no way to distribute the DB over AWS Regions. Even if you did you cloud only do a read copy. Should I just forget about relational data as globally distributed or should I pick another DB product from AWS?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use `API GW` + `Lambda` deployed to multiple regions (IMHO it is more serverless than opsless `Kubernetes/Fargate`, but not all apps are serverless friendly). Use `Route 53` with latency routing policy, so user will be routed to the region with the best latency.

2.) `Aurora` has also `Global` version (only MySQL) - https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/global-database/